# pgfplots: Tilted and Rotated sphere

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I can make sphere with `pgfplots` through the following code.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[%
        axis equal,
        width=10cm,
        height=10cm,
        axis lines = none,
    %    xlabel = {$x$},
    %    ylabel = {$y$},
    %    zlabel = {$z$},
        ticks=none,
        enlargelimits=0.3,
        view/h=45,
        scale uniformly strategy=units only,
    ]

 \addplot3[%
        opacity = 0.5,
        surf,
        z buffer = sort,
        samples = 21,
        variable = \u,
        variable y = \v,
        domain = 0:180,
        y domain = 0:360,
    ]
    ({cos(u)*sin(v)}, {sin(u)*sin(v)}, {cos(v)});

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm wondering how to get such rotated tilted sphere with `pgfplots`. Thanks

[image]

Comment: You can change the formula of the sphere such that principal axes are not on the xyz axes.

Comment: Thanks @percusse for your comment. Would you mind to more elaborate your comment?. Thanks

Comment: I mean it is possible to derive a formula for the rotated ellipsoid. And using that formula will directly draw the tilted sphere instead of canvas rotations etc. on the nonrotated one.

Comment: Do you want the sphere to be tilted with respect to the axes, i.e. should the z axis still point directly up, or would it also be okay if the axes were also tilted?

Comment: I want to have tilted and rotated sphere as shown in last figure. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208: So you will never switch on the axis lines (you will never remove `axis lines = none`), correct?

Comment: Yes, you right @jake.

Comment: Multiply the x component by 3 and y,z components by 0.5. Then use `view={55}{-100}`. Is that close?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## 1. Remarks

For explanations and implementations, see the "attached" document in section 3.

All the matrix multiplication stuff was done using Mathematica.

To learn more about rotations see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations or take a course on classical mechanics in your local university, especially rigid body dynamics.

## 2. Implementation

Compile with `pdflatex`, `lualatex` or `xelatex`. Tested on TeXLive 2013.

```
\documentclass[DIV=16]{scrartcl}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}

To rotate a body around a given axis, its parametrization vector $\boldsymbol{r}$
needs to be multiplied with the corresponding rotation matrix.

The parametrization vector of an ellipsoid is
%
\begin{equation*}
    \boldsymbol{r}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x \\
        y \\
        z \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a \sin\vartheta \cos\varphi \\
        b \sin\vartheta \sin\varphi \\
        c \cos\vartheta \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
%
with the half-axes $a,b,c$.

\textbf{Example:} Rotation around the $z$-axis at the angle $\alpha$.
%
\begin{align*}
    \boldsymbol{r}^*
    =
    \mathcal{R}_z(\alpha) \cdot \boldsymbol{r}
    &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha & 0 \\
        \sin\alpha & \cos\alpha & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a \sin\vartheta \cos\varphi \\
        b \sin\vartheta \sin\varphi \\
        c \cos\vartheta \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \\
    &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a \cos\alpha \sin\vartheta \cos\varphi - b \sin\alpha \sin\vartheta \sin\varphi \\
        b \cos\alpha \sin\vartheta \sin\varphi + a \sin\alpha \sin\vartheta \cos\varphi \\
        c \cos\vartheta \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{center}
    \def\a{2}
    \def\b{1}
    \def\c{0.5}
    \def\z{30}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
            axis equal,
            width=20cm,
            height=20cm,
            axis lines = center,
            ticks=none,
            view/h=45,
            enlargelimits=0.3,
            scale uniformly strategy=units only,
        ]

            \addplot3[%
                opacity = 0.5,
                surf,
                z buffer = sort,
                samples = 21,
                variable = \u,
                variable y = \v,
                domain = 0:180,
                y domain = 0:360,
            ]
            (
                {\a*cos(\z)*sin(u)*cos(v) + \b*sin(\z)*sin(u)*sin(v)},
                {\b*cos(\z)*sin(u)*sin(v) - \a*sin(\z)*sin(u)*cos(v)},
                {\c*cos(u)}
            );
    ,
    ,

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\textbf{Example:} Rotation around the $z$-axis at the angle $\alpha$ and the $x$-axis at the angle $\beta$. This is analogous to the example above except, that now we need to multiply the vector with two rotation matrices. Keep in mind, that rotations do not commute! That means if you rotate around the $z$-axis first and then around the $x$-axis you are really rotating around the $x^*$-axis, which was created when rotating around the $z$-axis.
%
\begin{align*}
    \boldsymbol{r}^*
    &=
    \mathcal{R}_x(\beta) \cdot \mathcal{R}_z(\alpha) \cdot \boldsymbol{r}
    \\
    &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & \cos\beta & -\sin\beta\\
        0 & \sin\beta & \cos\beta \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha & 0 \\
        \sin\alpha & \cos\alpha & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a \sin\vartheta \cos\varphi \\
        b \sin\vartheta \sin\varphi \\
        c \cos\vartheta \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \\
    &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a \cos\alpha \cos\varphi \sin\vartheta
        - b \sin\alpha \sin\vartheta \sin\varphi
    \\
        - c \cos\vartheta \sin\beta
        + a \cos\beta \cos\varphi \sin\alpha \sin\vartheta
        + b \cos\alpha \cos\beta \sin\vartheta \sin\varphi
    \\
        c \cos\beta \cos\vartheta
        + a \cos\varphi \sin\alpha \sin\beta \sin\vartheta
        + b \cos\alpha \sin\beta \sin\vartheta \sin\varphi \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{center}
    \def\a{2}
    \def\b{1}
    \def\c{0.5}
    \def\z{30}
    \def\x{15}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
            axis equal,
            width=20cm,
            height=20cm,
            axis lines = center,
            ticks=none,
            view/h=45,
            enlargelimits=0.3,
            scale uniformly strategy=units only,
        ]

            \addplot3[%
                opacity = 0.5,
                surf,
                z buffer = sort,
                samples = 21,
                variable = \u,
                variable y = \v,
                domain = 0:180,
                y domain = 0:360,
            ]
            (
                {\a*cos(v)*cos(\z)*sin(u) - \b*sin(u)*sin(v)*sin(\z)},
                {\b*cos(\x)*cos(\z)*sin(u)*sin(v) - \c*cos(u)*sin(\x) + \a*cos(v)*cos(\x)*sin(u)*sin(\z)},
                {\c*cos(u)*cos(\x) + \b*cos(\z)*sin(u)*sin(v)*sin(\x) + \a*cos(v)*sin(u)*sin(\x)*sin(\z)}
            );

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

For more information about rotation matrices see \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations}.

\end{document}
```

## 3. Output

On writeLaTeX, with a few modifications proposed by [percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235/percusse), thank you: https://www.writelatex.com/283014krmwmg

> [image]

Comment: This is probably one of the right places to use `compat=newest` then it will use whatever the last version is installed on the server. You also need to take out `scale uniformly strategy=units only,` line to make it work on writelatex

Comment: @percusse Thank you very much. I will try it later and update my post, if it works.